# Php code to randomly pick links And Open

Tags: php, php-7

Im new to Php. I kinda need code to open Links in browser when script is loaded.
heres my code below.

```
<?php
$links = array_open("https://stackoverflow.com/",
                    "https://outlook.office.com/",
                    "https://www.protectedtext.com/", 
                    "https://www.adobe.com/",
                    "https://www.linkedin.com");
echo $links[array_rand($links)];
?>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what your question is?

Comment: Got an answer already

Answer (score 0):

Hi change `array_open` to `array`

```
<?php
$links = array("https://stackoverflow.com/", "https://outlook.office.com/", "https://www.protectedtext.com/", "https://www.adobe.com/", "https://www.linkedin.com");
echo $links[array_rand($links)];
?>
```

And if you want to send the browser to the link you would send a location header like so...

```
<?php
$links = array("https://stackoverflow.com/", "https://outlook.office.com/", "https://www.protectedtext.com/", "https://www.adobe.com/", "https://www.linkedin.com");
header('Location: ' . $links[array_rand($links)]);
exit;
?>
```